# Grouping and transposing data in excel

Tags: excel, grouping, transpose

i'm trying to create an excel spreadsheet to be used to perform some basic "planning".

In one sheet I have a list of couples:

[image: spreeadsheet 1]

In a separate sheet I need to rearrange such data in the following way:

[image: spreadsheet 2]

So basically I need to group the items by week number and transpose the items associated with each week number horizontally.

Does anyone know if this is feasible with excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **Pivot Table** will quickly handle that job.

[image: img]

---

### More Information:

- Office.com : [Create a PivotTable to analyze worksheet data](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)
- Medium : [Microsoft Excel: Data Analysis; Getting Started with Pivot Tables](https://medium.com/lets-excel/microsoft-excel-data-analysis-getting-started-with-pivot-tables-826597f2d160)
- Tech Soup : [Getting Started with Pivot Tables in Excel](https://www.techsoupcanada.ca/en/community/blog/getting-started-with-pivot-tables-in-excel)

Answer (score 0):

This is the formula you need:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$5:$C$11,SMALL(IF($B$5:$B$11=$E5,ROW($C$5:$C$11)-MIN(ROW($C$5:$C$11))+1),COLUMNS($E$5:E5))),"")
```

Just put it on cell `E5` press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> for an array formula and drag along.

[image]